# If I freely described, in words and pictures, to individual companies(not "publicly") could I patent it, if no prior art?

Tags: provisional-application, public-disclosure

I have developed a grain drying/storage system, which I started documenting in 2008. I have shown this system, in general, to individual manufacturers and organizations without monetary compensation but never publicly put it out on the internet. Did this ruin my opportunity to patent?

Comment: Was there an understanding that the information was confidential and not to be shared?

Comment: There was nothing signed. All where casual general presentations.

Comment: If  the first outside presentation was more than a year ago and you didn't at least say - this is my confidential information, please keep it to yourselves, it would most likely  be considered - "available to the public" and therefore not patentable in the U.S.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I’d encourage you to put your last comment in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the first outside presentation was more than a year ago and you didn't at least say - "this is my confidential information, please keep it to yourselves", it would most likely be considered, in the words of 35 USC 102, "available to the public"  and therefore not patentable in the U.S. As a generalization, most places in the world do not have a grace period but also have different rules about what constitutes a breaking of novelty.